# C++ ( using file data to make calculation through functions)

Tags: c++

how to use the file after reading it in a function,and make the calculation in another function ?

here is the code that i was trying to make ..

```
void readFile(ifstream&); //file reading 

void DisplayAdd(ifstream& somefile);  //here what i don't understand do i use void or int !  
//and how is it going to use the data from the file !!


int main()
{
ifstream inputfile;
inputfile.open("numbers.txt");
readFile(inputfile);         //calling function to make reading file
DisplayAdd(inputfile);      //calling function to make addition
}
inputfile.close(); //closing file
return 0;
}

void readFile(ifstream& somefile) //reading data from file ..
{
double num1,num2,num3,num4,num5;
while(somefile>>num1>>num2>>num3>>num4>>num5)
    cout<<num1<<endl<<num2<<endl<<num3<<endl<<num4<<endl<<num5<<endl;
}

void DisplayAdd(ifstream& somefile) //how to make the calculation here is it like this !
{cout<<num1+num2+num3+num4+num5;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: what do you mean by "clarify the file"? sample of your work so far would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // you include HEADER needed for files using

using namespace std;

ifstream f("date.txt"); // you DECLARE the FILE data

int returnNumber(); // you PROTOTYPE your function (I guess you know about this)
int nr, a = 10, b = 10; // you declare your GLOBAL variables



int main()
{
    cout << returnNumber(); // you SHOW the number you got after calculation on screen
    return 0;
}


int returnNumber(){ // here's the function; int type because you return a integer value
    f >> nr; // you READ the VALUE from the file
    nr = nr + a + b; // you make a CALCULATION inside function
    return nr; // you RETURN the number
}
```

Comment: you are awesome ,Thanks a lot …,,, going to write the code now and see what will happen ...